# Read keyword arguments from a csv file

Tags: python, pandas, function, csv, keyword-argument

I have written a function that looks like:

```
def func(id, list, **kwargs):
    return
```

where id is the group id, list is some task to perform, and keyword argument is additional task and may or may not have. So each time when the function is run, it calls something like:

```
func(18, [1,3], task_a = ['x'], task_b=['y', 'z'])
```

I need to loop this over all group ids. The tricky thing is that each group may have different number and names of keyword arguments. The end user wants to give me the list in csv file, but I am not sure what is the best format and how should i read the data and pass it to my function. For example, for group id and list, I can have something like this in a csv:

```
groupid    list
18         [1,3]
23         [1,4,8]
```

but where and how should i store the keyword arguments? I can't store each task as a column because groupid shares different keyword argument. It's almost like I want to write ONE csv column as a dictionary by itself:

```
groupid    list       keyword
18         [1,3]      task_a: ['x']; task_b:['y', 'z']
23         [1,4,8]    task_c: ['j']
```

So how should I ask the end users to store them and how can my python pandas read them and convert them to keyword arguments for my function?

Comment: Genuine question, as I don't use JSON much, but... JSON? (Nesting JSON in a CSV, or a database, has its uses, but can also be a pain to deal with. Which is why I havne't done it much.)

Comment: the issue is more on the end users, who use only excel (entered manually) to give me the list to run. If there is no other solutions, I will ask them to enter the 'keyword' column as {task_a: ['x']; task_b:['y', 'z']} and I will just read them as they are and use some eval function to convert to dictionary

Comment: Got it. a list or non-comma delimited list seems like it would be easiest, from what you've said. But I admit your use case sounds a little novel.